# Auto imports in vscode-scss

Tags: visual-studio-code, sass, intellisense

I've recently started using scss and the best extension providing intellisense for scss out there seems to be [`vscode-scss`](https://github.com/mrmlnc/vscode-scss). But I don't understand, how to make it add `@use` or at least `@import` rules automatically. It sees variables and mixins from different files, but it writes `@import 'blabla' (implicitly)`, but I want an explicit import rule, preferable `@use`, at the top of my file. Does this feature exist at all? I'm struggling to open an issue on github, because I think I'm just don't gettting something right.

Comment: hello, are you found solution?

Comment: @kitsoRik, no, maybe there is one, but I didn't manage to find it. So I have to type it manually

Comment: @AlexChasin - yeah, you may copy it, when popover menu is open you may copy path from description of extension, https://imgur.com/lPIig8w